How to integrate outlines with LlamaIndex
I am working on creating an LLM for my company and then I am using Llama model for testing right now . Until Now, I have been using Deepeval library for evaluating my LLM. But, Sometimes the json output generated has some elements that cannot be converted into a json while trying to parse it (eg of these elements are: "..." etc). I want to integrate Outlines library with my Llama Index. Is there any way to do so?
